# Yii2 Failing to instantiate component or class "db"

Tags: yii2, migration

I use a Yii2 console application to run migrations. It's a very basic app, that goes like this (yii.php in the / folder of the project):

```
<?php

    require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
    require __DIR__ . '/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/Yii.php';
    $config = require __DIR__ . '/config/console.php';

    (new yii\console\Application($config))->run();

?>
```

So when i run

```
php yii.php
```

Everything's fine, but when i run

```
php yii.php migrate/create create_user_table
```

I am getting an error message:

```
Error: Failed to instantiate component or class "db".
```

My Yii is v2.0.15.1

UPD 19:32 30/12/2018
When I add a db config to a config/console.php like this:

```
    return [
    'id' => 'school-console',
    'basePath' => dirname(__DIR__),
    'db' => [
              'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
              'dsn' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=school',
              'username' => 'root',
              'password' => 'Taras1love',
              'charset' => 'utf8',
    ]
];
```

I get this:

```
Error: Setting read-only property: yii\console\Application::db
```

Comment: looks like you are missing the database component configurations can you add your `config/console.php` file?

Comment: `return [
 'id' => 'myapp-console',
 'basePath' => dirname(__DIR__)
];`

Comment: Do you resolve this problem? 
I have the same when I deploy yii in centos. But it is fine on the local development.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing the database component configurations for the console application you need to add the following inside the `config/console.php` file. As you are usign the `basic-app` for Yii2 you must have a `db.php` file with the database configurations, you need to include it like below

```
//this goes on the top of your `console.php` file 
$db = require __DIR__ . '/db.php',

return [
    'id' => 'myapp-console', 
    'basePath' => dirname(__DIR__)
    //add the db component
    'components' => [
        'db' => $db,
    ]
];
```

Your `db.php` should be like below inside the `config` folder, change the values for the `username`, `password` and `dbname`.

```
<?php

return [
    'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
    'dsn' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=YOUR_DB_NAME',
    'username' => 'DB_USER',
    'password' => 'DB_PASS',
    'charset' => 'utf8',
];
```

or you can assign it inside the `config/console.php` if you dont want to create a separate file

```
return [
    'id' => 'myapp-console', 
    'basePath' => dirname(__DIR__)
    //add the db component
    'components' => [
        'db' => [
           'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
           'dsn' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=YOUR_DB_NAME',
           'username' => 'DB_USER',
           'password' => 'DB_PASS',
           'charset' => 'utf8',
        ]
    ]
];
```

Comment: @tnsaturday you are welcome , glad it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

I found that I got this problem if I ran yii directly from vendor/bin.
If I went to the console directory and ran it from there using ./yii, I did not get this error and was able to create the migration.

In other words:

```
cd <project-root>/vendor/bin
yii migrate/create xxx
```

did not work

But:

```
cd <project-root>/console
./yii migrate/create xxx
```

did work

Comment: you dont go inside any of the apps `console` or `fronetned` to run themigrations but you stay on the roo i.e `<project-root>` only to run the migrations

Answer (score 0):

this happened to me because I accidentally renamed my migration and it was not matching the file name